# Generating a random number in a loop

Tags: java, loops, random

I'd like to know how would you generate a random numbers in the loop. I know I should use `java.util.random`, but i'd like to know how should I do it,because the thing is, that I need to generate as many item random numbers the program needs, because its sorting algorithm.

For example, first of all, you need to choose which method are you using (eg. 1), after that when you input number, the next you need to input count items (eg. 5), and after that, you need to enter items (so if you have 5 items, you need to enter 5 different items and after that sorting will happen.

I need to generate these numbers because if I need to have for example 10000 count I don't want to enter manually 10k of numbers so it would be nice to make it automatically.

Hopefully you can help me! Sorry if i'm wrong or anything, it's my first post here. :)

p.s. I added the part of code here so you can see my loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { //3.part - array output

    int numurs;

        int metode;
        System.out.println("Name Surname RDBF0 student no");
        System.out.print("method: ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (sc.hasNextInt()){
            numurs = sc.nextInt();
        } 
        else
        {
            System.out.println("input-output error");
            sc.close();
            return;
        }

        if (numurs != 1 && numurs != 2) {
            System.out.println("input-output error");
                sc.close();
                return;
        }



        System.out.print("count: ");
            if (sc.hasNextInt())
                metode = sc.nextInt();

            else {
                System.out.println("input-output error");
                sc.close();
                return;
            }


        int a[] = new int[metode];

        System.out.println("items: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            if (sc.hasNextInt())
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();

        else {
            System.out.println("input-output error");
            sc.close();
            return;
            }
        }
        sc.close();      

        switch (numurs) {

        case 1: firstMethod(a);
        break;
        case 2: secondMethod(a);
        break;

        default:
            System.out.println("input-output error");
        return;
        }
        System.out.println("sorted: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        } 
    }
```

Comment: How about a... loop?

Comment: @Jyr I wan't to replace lines where user needs to input those item numbers so `util.random` could fill all needed numbers automatically. This is the loop where count happens: 
`System.out.print("count: ");
            if (sc.hasNextInt())
                metode = sc.nextInt();

            else {
                System.out.println("input-output error");
                sc.close();
                return;
            }


        int a[] = new int[metode];`

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a random number using Random class as you said:

```
Random rand = new Random();
//if you want the random number to be between 0 and maxValue
int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(maxValue);

//if you want it to be between minValue and maxValue, it should look like this
int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(maxValue) + minValue;
```

Comment: Where should I write these lines? Because I have a loop where this random number output happens.You can have a look at exact loop [here](http://pastebin.com/PM6pkyB7)

Comment: When you want to capture the value you need, instead of using Scanner you can use the methods above.
For instance metode = rand.nextInt(5000);

Comment: Ok so did try this. No compilation errors or anything, but I can't can't see why it's just not working. So [here](http://pastebin.com/XgKM4cX3) is what I did. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: I tried to use this code anywhere, but still it does not make any difference

Comment: Try to adapt this with your requirement:
Random rand = new Random();
int a[] = new int[metode];
System.out.println("items: ");
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   a[i] = rand.nextInt(5000); //a[i] will have different values
}